# Calculate $\iint_S yds$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

> Calculate the surface integral
> $$\iint_S yds$$
> where $S$ is the part of surface $x=2y^2+1~(y>0)$ bounded by $x = y^2+z^2,~x=2,~x=3$

I drew the graph

[image]

but still it's not obvious how to proceed. It seems I can't get surface integral well, unfortunately.

- How can I parametrize this region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seeks you to evaluate $ \displaystyle \iint_S y \ ds$ where $S$ is part of the surfacec $x = 2y^2+1~(y>0)$.

Surface $S$ is a parabolic cylinder and all points on its surface can be uniquely identified if we know $x$ and $z$ coordinates OR we know $y$ and $z$ coordinates.

So parametrize surface $S$ either in terms of $(x, z)$ or in terms of $(y, z)$.

$r(y, z) = (2y^2+1, y, z), \ y \geq 0$

Having parametrized the surface, now find $|r_y \times r_z|$.

To find bounds for the integral, note that
$S$ is bound between $2 \leq x \leq 3$ and paraboloid $x = y^2 + z^2$.

You can check that between $x = 2$ and $x = 3$, there is part of $S$ inside the paraboloid. At their intersection,

$x = 2y^2 + 1 = y^2 + z^2 \implies - \sqrt{y^2 + 1} \leq z \leq \sqrt{y^2+1}$

Now for surface $S$, at $x = 2, y = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and at $x = 3, y = 1$.

Integral to find surface area,

$\displaystyle \iint y \ |r_y \times r_z| \ dz \ dy$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you again, yes I can!

Comment: Could you verify me here as well, if you have a chance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4167803/is-int-c-fracdxdyxy-0